# How can I tell if I have a stock recovery?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, recovery-mode, stock-rom

I need to get rid of the yellow triangle in download mode on a Samsung Galaxy S3 (Android 4.3), for this I tried to use [Triangle Away](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.triangleaway). It failed to reset the counter.

The app mentions that on some devices, both the ROM and the recovery must be stock. The ROM is but I do not know about the recovery. How can I check if it is stock?

The one I have currently looks like this:

[image: recovery screenshot]

<sup>Click image for larger version</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the screenshot, you have the stock recovery.

The stock recovery normally shows "Android System Recovery <3e>" whereas custom recoveries tend to have their name instead. There are two popular custom recoveries both of which look quite different to the one in your screenshot

ClockworkMod:

[image: clockworkmod recovery]

TWRP:

[image: TWRP Recovery]