# Is it effectively possible to get rid of the yellow triangle in download mode on an S3 with 4.3?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, rom-flashing, stock-android

I am trying to get rid of the yellow triangle visible just prior to download mode (`Volume-Down` + `Home` + `Power`). There is no shortage of tutorials about how do this, but after having tried all the solutions I could find I am wondering if it is at all possible in my case

- This is a Samsung Galaxy S3 (GT-I9300)
- I have the stock ROM (Android 4.3), it has never been flashed
- [I have stock recovery](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/71485/how-can-i-tell-if-i-have-a-stock-recovery) (thanks [bmdixon](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/30530/bmdixon)) - which has also not been flashed
- I tried to use [Triangle Away](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.triangleaway) (having rooted the phone before)

When going into download mode I have

```
CUSTOM BINARY DOWNLOAD: No
CURRENT BINARY: Samsung Official
SYSTEM STATUS: Official
```

For some mysterious reason the phone thinks it has been flashed (it went once to an official Samsung repair so maybe it got the triangle there).

I read that the introduction of Knox in 4.3 makes resetting the counter impossible. However I do not have Knox (even though the phone was updated OTA to 4.3, maybe this is because I am in France).

Is there a solution worth trying to remove the yellow triangle?

(for the story: I went to an official Samsung repair shop and they discovered (together with me) that there is the infamous yellow triangle. While the issue I am having is probably mechanical and the warranty still applies according to European legislation, I do not want to get into lengthy discussions with Samsung. It does not help that I have only 3 days of warranty left...)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you're not using KNOX you don't need to worry about the triangle status. Second, to use [TriangleAway](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s2/orig-development/2013-10-04-triangleaway-v3-10-t1494114) you **have to be rooted, with [SuperSU](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1538053)**. If the Google Play version doesn't work, try the latest beta [v1.99r3](http://download.chainfire.eu/446/SuperSU/UPDATE-SuperSU-v1.99r3.zip) which should fix many SEAndroid related issues. In fact it is highly recommended that you get rooted, so that you can remove both KNOX, OTA updates, and the triangle, before you will receive the next OTA update which may completely lock down your device. If you have never flashed your phone, and it is showing the triangle, you have either received a refurbished device or you have been cheated by the seller. The triangle is an indication that a OTP (one time programmable) fuse has been blown in the past, due to flashing.

Comment: I do not worry about the triangle status - this is more Samsung which will, and tell me that my warranty is void. I did root the phone before using Triangle Away (I will add that to the description). The problem is that Triangle Away did not manage to remove it, despite the prereqs (stock Android & recovery)